# Microsoft Teams connector. removeUrl page is not being loaded

Tags: microsoft-teams, connector

When I set up may connector, I call microsoftTeams.settings.setSettings:

```
            microsoftTeams.settings.setSettings({
                entityId: "MyConnector002",
                contentUrl: `https://msteams.whatever.com/connectorsetup.html`,
                removeUrl: `https://msteams.whatever.com/connectorremove.html`,
                configName: 'Active'
            });
```

I know the settings are being called at the right time because the contentUrl page is appearing when it should.  However my connectorremove.html page is not being loaded when I click the "remove" button from the "configure" list ("manage" button).  The connector does remove, but the page at my configured removeUrl is not loaded.

I've set console.log, alert and debugger statements at the top of the connectorremove.html page, and they are never hit.  So obviously my call to  microsoftTeams.settings.registerOnRemoveHandler isn't being hit.   If I just copy and paste the removeUrl into a browser address field, it loads fine.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your query. Also could you please share the repro steps with screenshots and documentation if you are following any.
Could you please let me know which connector you are implementing.

Answer (score 1):

I found what I was doing wrong.  The removeUrl page should not be loading in the use case where you select your connector in the "Manage"/"Configured" list, click the "1 configured", then click the "Manage" button.  This brings up the page you specified in the settings' contentUrl.  You click the "remove" button at the bottom of that page and, instead of the removeUrl being involved, it expects that in the contentUrl page you have set up a remove handler function using the settings.registerRemoveHandler function.